# Read-Only properties within Browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I’m trying to list all read only native properties the browser JavaScript api has , like window.top or window/document.location .
I didn’t manage to find such list and I googled a lot :(.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: `console.log(window)` ?

Comment: Like the list on MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @epascarello   maybe I was misunderstood, I need to find all unhijackable properties that you cannot override or set a getter/setter on

Comment: @avidahan so that page listed the properties and they have read only labels on them. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: @epascarello  not exactly , for example take the window.parent it is listed as read only but you can set a getter and return whatever you want , what I would like to know is what is the “secure” properties

Comment: @avidahan so loop over and set and get and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, you're looking for all readonly `window` object properties. Someone already linked you to this [MDN list of window properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

If you're looking for an actual JavaScript solution, you can loop through the properties on the `window` object and check its `writable` status via [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).

Example:

```
for (const prop in window) {
    // using destructuring here
    const { writable } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, prop);

    // an object property is by default writable,
    // absence of writable prop is equivalent to `writable=true`
    if (writable != null && writable !== false) {
        console.log(prop, 'is writable');
    }
}
```

There's also `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` which allows you to get all props in one shot.

EDIT

Note that this will include global libraries like jQuery and Google Analytics, your best bet is sticking to a fixed list, like the one on MDN. If you're working with a plain HTML page that you have full control over with only vanilla JS, you should be fine.